# How to calculate an ETA for a LINQ pipeline to complete?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, time, system.reactive

I would like to inform the user about the estimated time that remains to finish an operation. The long operation happens inside a sequence like this:

```
var processedItems = items.Select(x => Process(x));
```

Each `Process(x)` call could take a few seconds to complete.

I would like to know a simple and clean way to dynamically estimate the remaining as the enumerable is projected.

Maybe using `System.Reactive`?

Comment: An `IEnumerable` doesn't have a `Count` property though, in fact, it could go on forever (imagine a network stream for example)

Comment: And System.Reactive really just changes a pull to a push model, which doesn't change the underlying problem at all.

Comment: OK, you see the problem. Do you know any mechanism to "sample" the evolution of long process in order to provide an ETA?

Comment: But if you don't know how many items you are looping over, you can't predict when it will finish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all this is impossible to do with an [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.7.1) because there's no way to get the number of elements. For this to work you should use anything that implements [`ICollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.1) instead, that way you can get the [number of items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.count?view=netframework-4.7.1).

Secondly, you can't really use the existing `Select` methods (well not without some hacking) but you can write your own. Here's something I knocked up that will call an action for every element in a list during the projection.

First a class to hold the details of the current progress.

```
public class SelectProgress
{
    public decimal Percentage { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeTaken { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan EstimatedTotalTime { get; set; }
}
```

And the custom `Select` method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(
    this ICollection<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, TResult> selector, 
    Action<SelectProgress> timeRemaining)
{
    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();
    var counter = 0;
    foreach (var element in source)
    {
        yield return selector(element);
        counter++;
        timeRemaining?.Invoke(new SelectProgress
        {
            Percentage = counter/(decimal)source.Count,
            TimeTaken = timer.Elapsed,
            EstimatedTotalTime = 
                TimeSpan.FromTicks(timer.Elapsed.Ticks/counter * source.Count)
        });
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
//Let's have a list of numbers to play with
var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).ToList();

var results = list.Select(
    i => 
    {
        //Just an artificial delay
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        //Return the string representation of the number, you know,
        //just something fun to do here really
        return i.ToString();
    }, 
    //Just going to output the values here, but you can choose to do whatever you like
    p => Console.WriteLine(
        $"{p.Percentage:P2}: Taken: {p.TimeTaken}, Total: {p.EstimatedTotalTime}"))
    .ToList();
```

This code will generate output something like this:

```
5.00%: Time taken: 00:00:01.0007261, Estimated total: 00:00:20.0158420
10.00%: Time taken: 00:00:02.0015503, Estimated total: 00:00:20.0155100
15.00%: Time taken: 00:00:03.0017421, Estimated total: 00:00:20.0116180
<snip>
90.00%: Time taken: 00:00:18.0101580, Estimated total: 00:00:20.0112860
95.00%: Time taken: 00:00:19.0103062, Estimated total: 00:00:20.0108480
100.00%: Time taken: 00:00:20.0107314, Estimated total: 00:00:20.0107320
```

Comment: Great! BTW, I think the Stop method in stopwatch should be called after the actual processing has finished (after the foreach), right?

Comment: Well you can do that but it's pointless. The stopwatch will get disposed of anyway.

Comment: @DavidG - There's nothing in your code that disposes of the `Stopwatch`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Enigmativity There's nothing to dispose, Stopwatch doesn't implement IDisposable and internally doesn't use any resources at all. So when the variable goes out of scope, it's gone.

Comment: @DavidG - Yes, I got a bit confused when you said "stopwatch will get disposed of anyway". You meant collected, right?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, you're right. I wrote those comments in airports and didn't really sense check. To be clear, `Stopwatch` has no unmanaged resources and hence doesn't require disposal. The `Stop` method doesn't need to be called due to the internal mechanism of the object. I believe it's a simple wrapper around perf counters and only keeps a couple of numbers to determine how much time has passed. And yes, the object will get collected when it goes out of scope. :)